# Angular 2/4: what is the difference between the scripts.bundle.js and the vendor.bundle.js?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular 4: after running the command: `ng build` I have this structure

```
0.chunk.js      favicon.ico           polyfills.bundle.js.map
0.chunk.js.map  index.html            scripts.bundle.js
1.chunk.js      inline.bundle.js      scripts.bundle.js.map
1.chunk.js.map  inline.bundle.js.map  styles.bundle.js
2.chunk.js      main.bundle.js        styles.bundle.js.map
2.chunk.js.map  main.bundle.js.map    vendor.bundle.js
assets          polyfills.bundle.js   vendor.bundle.js.map
```

> What is the difference between the `scripts.bundle.js` and the `vendor.bundle.js`?

I think difference is, that the `scripts.bundle.js` holds all external `.js` files and the `vendor.bundle.js` holds all created modules.

**EDIT**

> but I can import `.js` files from `node_modules` into the `vendor.bundle.js` and the `scripts.bundle.js`. What the best approach is: importing `.js` files into modules or adding them into the `.angular-cli.json`s `scripts` object?

*~Thanks a lot for your help!*

Comment: I just updated the answer to adress your question update

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`scripts.bundle.js` represents `scripts` section that you configured in `.angular-cli.json`
`vendor.bundle.js` contains `npm modules` you are referencing in your `app.module`.

> The better way to figure out what is inside your bundles is to use
>   [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)

Add `"analyze": "ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",` to your `package.json` and once you `npm install webpack-bundle-analyzer` just run `npm run analyze`

The purpose of `scripts` section of `.angular-cli.json` is to handle legacy scripts but also you can use that to improve your lazy loading story. Say only your chunks relying on some particular `npm module`. In such case there is no need to have that npm module placed in to `vendor.bundle.js` as it can be loaded just before the related chunk is loaded.

More details on scripts section on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Comment: if I add `.js` file into `angular-cli.json` `scripts` file would load on app start, but I want use thous `.js` files in lazy loading module?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov you have to set `"lazy": true` if you want to exclude any of particular `scripts` from being loaded in `index.html` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts and also check out this issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6018 for more details on that matter.

Comment: Yeah it's worked, it loaded thous scripts lazily, but I wanted use them when I load certain page///